# BG_JOB_ID differs from previous version

Tags: sql, oracle, jobs, oracle19c

In Oracle Database versions prior to 19c, `SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','BG_JOB_ID')` returned job id from `dba_jobs` (if it was run in background process).

From 19c release, the same statement returns absolutely different number, which doesn't correspond with `dba_jobs.job` id.

Is it bug or feature? How can I map 19c result with job id from `dba_jobs`?

I tried to map it through `v$Scheduler_Running_Jobs` and `dba_jobs_running`. It works, but is a bit confusing.

```
select SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','BG_JOB_ID') from dual
```

in background session.

Answer (score 2):

dbms_job is deprecated since Oracle 12.2.0.1, so during upgrade to Oracle 19c the jobs will be converted from dbms_job to dbms_scheduler jobs. Mike Dietrich describes the details in his blog post [dbms_job-behavior-change-in-oracle-19c-during-upgrade/](https://mikedietrichde.com/2019/05/24/dbms_job-behavior-change-in-oracle-19c-during-upgrade/) I think the BG_JOB_ID displays the dbms_scheduler id for migrated jobs.